# Redirect all to different domain except wp-admin and wp-json

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all pages to http://www.expample2.com except the wp-admin and wp-json.

For example the user is able to login to http://www.example1.com/wp-admin and the wp-json plugin still has to work which is in http://www.example1.com/wp-json/...

Also within the wp-admin the user can click to show a post for example. http://www.example1.com/post/title but I want this to point to http://www.example2.com/book/title

However in order for the json to work right this script has to work to I think:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-json.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.com$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Place this inside your `<VirtualHost>` for your `www.example1.com`.
The snippet you included in the question looks like the standard Wordpress `.htaccess` file in its root folder, yes? That is why it is better to change your Apache conf.

Comment: I had to add some other RewriteCond wp-login and wp-content in order for the admin part to work. But for some reason wp-json still redirects to example2.com. It goes straight to example2.com/index.php

Comment: You could try something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-.*` and redirect all URLs starting with **wp-**. As for why the `wp-json` isn't redirecting, I would turn up the logging http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html - Apache Rewrite Logging - or look in the Apache logs usually in `/var/log/apache2/` and see if the HTTP requests are actually coming in as `/wp-json/`...

Comment: The above should say "redirect all URLs NOT starting with **wp-**".

Comment: That's a great way to include all wp related folders indeed. I fixed my problem by just redirecting the post folder and root. So I leaved the rest out. So the redirects are kinda reversed.